# How to send message in loop of discord.py?

Tags: python, loops, discord, discord.py

I want to make my bot be able to send message in loop with custom loop time
eg. !remind 60s would make the bot say reminder in 60 seconds
eg. !remind 23s would make the bot say reminder in 23 seconds

I currently have this, but it doesn't work.
Any help would be appreciated and if you could also provide a example that would be great. Thanks

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=timeP)
async def Reminder():

timeP = 5
channel = client.get_channel(717689495620681731)
await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('online'))
print('test')
await channel.send('<@&717696163574186026> here')
```

Comment: I would reccomend looking into ```asyncio``` especially ```asyncio.create_task``` https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `task` decorator from discord.py :

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import task

@tasks.loop(seconds=x) #you can also have minutes=x or hours=x
    async def printer(self):
        channel = client.get_channel(717689495620681731)
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('online'))
        print('test')
        await channel.send('<@&717696163574186026> here')
```